# Fill Array with Pixel Location

Tags: javascript

I have a logo in a `header/nav` tag, and when the user scrolls down, the header logo changes to a smaller image in order to shrink down the `header` size. The intent is to have the image load with the first class, and then changes class on scroll down, and then changes class again on scroll up. I currently have this code:

```
function logoChange() {
    var logoImg = document.getElementById("logoImg");
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var img = document.getElementById("logoImg");

    if (scrollTop > 20) {
        logoImg.setAttribute("src", "images/logos/ico_curve.png");
        img.setAttribute("class", "favicon");
    } else {
        logoImg.setAttribute("src", "images/logos/M&A_logo.png");
        img.setAttribute("class", "logoRevert");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", logoChange);
```

It works with the exception that as soon as the user begins to scroll, the function runs and changes the image class before I want the else block of code to execute. I only want the else clause to execute after the if clause is true.

So I though about making an array populated with pixel count, but `New Array(21).fill(window.scrollY);` populates the entire array immediately, as it should. And `let pixelArray = [window.scrollY];` only populates the array with one array item.

I only want the else clause to execute after the if clause is true, which is when the user has scrolled down more than 20 pixels. If there's a better way to do it than an array, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I only want the else clause to execute after the if clause is true"*... I beg your pardon?

Comment: I don't want the else clause to execute until the user scroll back up above 20 pixels or less, which means the if clause would have to be true first.

Comment: Have another if statement checking if `img.classList.contains('favicon')`, then you know it's been through the if?

Comment: I think that might work

Comment: I fail to understand why... why would you need the `if`-statement to be `true` once? You have two states and one of them defines the look under 20px scrolling and one over 20px, if I am correct?
So the look of the page before scrolling should be exactly the one after...

Comment: @Light, thanks! Works perfectly!!!

Comment: @Light, how can I give you credit for answering the question? I already gave you a plus one.

Comment: I've moved my comment into the answer section, partly for my e-points, partly for question/answer purposes - You would chose that as the accepted answer

Comment: Smile :) Did any of you think about how small a 20 pixel distance is ? It might be a idea to just increase the scroll limit to something bigger. I would check the page size for example first and would think about the logo size.... For testing purposes i sugegst to test with 100 pixel first...

Comment: @Thomas Ludewig, I might increase the pixel distance. It's really only for the affect of the sticky header, so that it moves a little before fixing itself to the top.

Comment: Make the damn thing fixed and you are done *grin*Your code looks fine so i was wondering what it can be. But on such Details yoiu can really waste hours :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Have another if statement checking if img.classList.contains('favicon'), then you know it's been through the if?" - Moved from my comments